# C - Add Item To Array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on a game modification for a third party game (a so called "mod"), and I want to add the player to an array.

I will explain the process of how it works. My code looks like this:

```
int numElements = 20;
int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;

Ped peds[arrSize];
peds[0] = numElements;

int countPeds = GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS(PLAYER_PED_ID(), peds, -1);
```

The game function called `GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS` will populate the `peds` array with IDs of the pedestrians walking around the `PLAYER_PED_ID` (our player).

**My goal here is to also add our player to this array aswell.** Right now, it only gathers the pedestrians around the player, and I want the player to be included in this array aswell.

I came to the conclusion that I should create a new array, and add the `PLAYER_PED_ID` to this new array, like so:

```
Ped newpeds[arrSize + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) newpeds[i] = peds[i];
newpeds[arrSize + 1] = PLAYER_PED_ID();
```

And then instead of using the `peds` array in my code, I will be using `newpeds`. But for some reason the modifications don't affect the player, but only the pedestrians around the player (like the first code example).

This is what my full code looks like:

```
int numElements = 20;
int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;

Ped peds[arrSize];
peds[0] = numElements;

int countPeds = GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS(pedID, peds, -1);

Ped newpeds[arrSize + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) newpeds[i] = peds[i];
newpeds[arrSize + 1] = PLAYER_PED_ID();

for (int i = 0; i < countPeds; i++) {
    Ped ped = newpeds[i * 2 + 2];

    //... 
}
```

How can I add the player to the array? Could it have something to do with the math? Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are trying to add **PLAYER_PED_ID()** at wrong index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) newpeds[i] = peds[i];
newpeds[arrSize + 1] = PLAYER_PED_ID();
```

You should be adding **PLAYER_PED_ID()** at :

```
newpeds[arrSize] = PLAYER_PED_ID();
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thanks for your reply. I've made the change to my code, however it still doesn't seem to count `PLAYER_PED_ID()` in.

Comment: Could it have something to do with `Ped ped = newpeds[i * 2 + 2];` not defining the indexes correctly?

Comment: if you  could explain the purpose of  accessing elements like this : [i * 2 + 2 ]

Comment: I've tried looking into why this is, but there's nearly no documentation about the `GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS` game function, and when I use `newpeds[i]` the game crashes. :(